# SMTP using nodemailer in nodejs without GMail

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am using node mailer with GMail

```
smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "myemail ",
        pass: "mypass"
    }
});
```

which is working fine, but I want to use my own email server instead of GMail.

This:

```
smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "mymailservr link url",
    port : 25
    auth: {
        user: "myemail ",
        pass: "mypass"
    }
});
```

It throws this error:

> connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: you sure the problem was not the typo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `service` option is only for [well-known services](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-wellknown#supported-services). To specify your own host, set [host](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport#usage).

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
    host: 'yourserver.com',
    port: 25,
    auth: {
        user: 'username',
        pass: 'password'
    }
});
```

Comment: m getting errror

{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  stage: 'init' }

Comment: @Hitu What exactly are you passing as `host`? Since you wrote url in your question, are you sure you pass an actual hostname and not an url? Try `ping yourhostname` on the command line.

Comment: host: 'exmaple.com.com.outbound10.mxlogic.net' like this

Comment: I was trying hell lot of things with `service` .. that one liner from u made all the differences .. thanks a lot

Comment: you sure the problem was not the typo? I get that feeling op just copy pasted your code.

Comment: This works smoothly for me. I used the outgoing port

Answer (score 4):

make sure you have the latest [NodeMailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) version installed

as of today (15-jan-2020) it is v6.4.2

```
npm install nodemailer --save
```

This should work:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: 'smtp.server.com', // <= your smtp server here
   port: 2525, // <= connection port
   // secure: true, // use SSL or not
   auth: {
      user: 'userId', // <= smtp login user
      pass: 'E73oiuoiC34lkjlkjlkjlkjA6Bok7DAD' // <= smtp login pass
   }
});

let mailOptions = {
   from: fromEmailAddress, // <= should be verified and accepted by service provider. ex. 'youremail@gmail.com'
   to: toEmailAddress, // <= recepient email address. ex. 'friendemail@gmail.com'
   subject: emailSubject, // <= email subject ex. 'Test email'
   //text: emailData.text, // <= for plain text emails. ex. 'Hello world'
   html: htmlTemplate // <= for html templated emails
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
   if (error) {
      return console.log(error.message);
   }
   console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
});
```

Hope this helps,
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an example of a free on-premises hosted "smtp server" that can be installed on a LAN ? I am confused, it appears that nodemailer can be used as an smtp server, but all examples require an EXTERNAL product as an smtp-server ?!

Answer (score 2):

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host : "example.com",
    port: 25,
    auth : {
        user : "username",
        pass : "password"
    }
}));
```